# handling table in SQLITE (android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to manage (create/delete/update) a table with 18 columns. Normally, for creating table, I use below codes. Is there any smarter way, like putting the column names in an array etc.? How people handle large tables?

Thanks for your help, as always.

```
private static final String COL1 = "col1";
private static final String COL2 = "col2";
private static final String COL3 = "col3";
........
........
private static final String COL18 = "col18";

public dbhandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL2 + " TEXT,"
                + COL3 + " TEXT," + .............................+ COL18 + " TEXT")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: if you will put field names in array then its difficult to handle 18 indexes and remember the name of field on any index. so i think best way is to make proper field name so you can easily use.

Comment: That is "Android" way. I don't know which disvantages come from simply use plain text (as `"CREATE TABLE t(a TEXT, b)"`, `"SELECT b FROM t"`, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make tuples (column name and type), and store these in an `Array`. In the `onCreate` you can loop over it and add it to the `CREATE_TABLE` string.

But unless you are going to change the columns a lot, a simple copy and paste of lines is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

A smarter way doing so is using `db4o` (database 4 objects). While creating a database like this has the following advantages:

1. It is purely based on object database.
2. No such mapping of tables like in sqlite.
3. Saves time and volume of code.
4. Reuse objects by saving and retrieving them as many times as you want.
5. Benefit from Native Queries.

For more info refer to: http://www.sohailaziz.com/2012/09/using-database-for-objects-db4o-in.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are use the large table the best way is use the SQLiteManager browser. Remaining all operation do in the normal .java file.If you are use 2 or more table use the SQLiteManager plug-in.